# SMS application is not sending special characters asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sms, sms-gateway

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that sends SMS from the web, problem is it doesn't send some special characters such as ~!@#$&, when I send something like &&&&, it doesn't send SMS, if I send something like dan&dan it will send the first dan and remove remaining character and word.

Hare is my code:

```
public ActionResult SendSms(SendBatch member)
{
    StreamReader objReader;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    string mess = member.Message;
    string cell = member.Cell;
    string pass = "mypassword";
    string user = "username";

    string baseurl = "http://bulksms.2way.co.za/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?" + "username=" + user + "&" + "password=" + pass + "&" + "message=" + mess + "&" + "msisdn=" + cell;

    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(baseurl);

    try
    {
        Stream objStream;
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
        objReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Hope someone can assist.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use Get method to call SMS web service, illegal characters automatically removed from your SMS. You need to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode characters before sending.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, can you show me how to that in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the light, i manage to find a solution using HttpUtility.UrlEncode:

```
public ActionResult SendSms(SendBatch member)
    {
        StreamReader objReader;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string mess = member.Message;
        string cell = member.Cell;
        string pass = "mypassword";
        string user = "username";

        string message = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mess, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        string baseurl = "http://bulksms.2way.co.za/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?" + "username=" + user + "&" + "password=" + pass + "&" + "message=" + message + "&" + "msisdn=" + cell;

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(baseurl);

        try
        {
            Stream objStream;
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
            objReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```